# How to request a new task when a process completes using the Python multiprocessing library?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Basically, I would like to have a pool to threads to perform some tasks for a given period of time.  I figured that the multiprocessing library in Python would be perfect for me to do this.  However, I cannot figure out a way, for when one of the processes finishes (and without waiting for the other threads in the pool to finish), to go back to the main thread and perform certain tasks (increment variables, check if the time threshold has been met, etc) to potentially start a new process with new parameters.  For example, here all of the arguments for the function are given upfront (1..10) for the pool of processes (4) to deal with:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
    print pool.map(f, range(10))          # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
```

However, since I need to perform some tasks for a specific period of time, this will not help me since I will not necessarily know how long these tasks will take to complete.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: use a shared queue between workers, and push the tasks there. see my sample implementation: http://integricho.github.io/2013/03/27/no-man-left-behind/

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions would be to use a shared queue. For example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def job(queue):
    while True:
        task = queue.get()
        print task*task

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create shared queue
    q = Queue()

    # create processes
    processes = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = Process(target=job, args=(q,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    # generate data
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(10):
            q.put(10*i+j)
        time.sleep(0.5)

    # join
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

I've added `time.sleep` to show how it works when data is added later (processes wait until something is available in shared queue).